# Setting up delegates in container view

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a container view in my Storyboard that displays another view controller that I already programmed and stuff. I want to communicate between the main View Controller and the contained-view controller. I know how to use delegates and I am comfortable with using them, however I normally set up delegates when I initialize a ViewController, however in this case I don't know where to apply this, since the view controller is already there per the storyboard. Normally I would do something like this:

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    func initializeVC() {
        resultsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "resultsView") as! GoalsVC
        resultsVC.calcDelegate = self //I set the "HomeVC" as the Delegate since it has all the functions I need
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, since I never really created this view controller via code, I don't know how to assign a delegate (specially setting the delegate to "self" (where Self is the main View Controller)

Comment: You can do this in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: As Evgeniy has said, you can do it in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, it is a very vague answer. on viewDidLoad() how do I do that? The other answers mostly recommend using prepareforsegue which is what I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign delegate in `prepareforsegue`. Like below code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "container_segue") {
        let controller = segue.destination as! containerController
        controller.delegate = self
    }
}
```

When project runs, this method called automatically because we had created segue in the storyboard.

By using `segue.identifier` you can check for which controller segue is going to happen and accordingly you can achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using storyboard for container view. There is a `segue` with `embed` type. Give this `segue` a `identifier`, say `MyContainedViewControllerSegueId`

Then in `prepare(for segue:`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "MyContainedViewControllerSegueId" {
            // here you get your contained view controller as `segue.destination`
            // cast it your subclassed view controller
            // use delegate on that subclassed view controller for communication purpose.
        }
    }
```